# Monogame Window opens in inconvenient location (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: monogame

I am working on a Monogame OpenGL project in VisualStudio 2013 and whenever I compile the project, the window opens down on the lower-right hand corner of the screen.

[image]

This is extremely annoying, especially given that I am working on a laptop without defined right/left click points on the trackpad, so the computer responds weirdly when I try to drag it back.

What causes this? Is it a screen resolution issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: What window? You mean what appears to be to the right of the clock and offscreen?

Comment: The game window (the one that opens when I compile). And yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: Try resizing Visual Studio so that it is not maximized and compile again.  Hopefully the window won't appear so offscreen.  Then you can move it.  Once moved; wait for compile to finish; maximize visual studio; compile.  Does it appear offscreen still?

Comment: Nothing has changed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of your `GameWindow` with its position property. According to the [current source](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/GameWindow.cs), it will work for any desktop OpenGL export.

It should use similar coordinates to your in-game positions, with (0, 0) at the top-left.